# Add 2 images to separate UIImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

I hava an app where i need to add 2 or more images. The images should be displayed in UIImageview. I use two separate buttons to add 2 images. i am able to add only one image. When i choose the second button, the image gets displayed on the first UIImageview. Here is the code where i do it.

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerUIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfoNSDictionary *)info {
    if(choosePhoto1){

       NSLog(@"buttonclicked:button1");

       theimageView1.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
       [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    }
    else if(choosePhoto2) {
         NSLog(@"buttonclicked:button2");

         theimageView2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

         [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   }

}
```

I want to know if this is the right way to do it or is there any other method. I looked in to the forums but there is no method for adding 2 pictures.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Viki

Comment: Foru;So you have 2 imageviews, and you want to add the same image to both of them?

Comment: i have 2 imageviews and i want to add two image each one in seperate UIImageView.

Answer (score 0):

One UIImageView displays a single image.  If you want to display two different images in two different places at the same time, then you need two UIImageView objects.    If you do have two UIImageView objects, and only one is changing, perhaps in interface builder you set both outlets to one UIImageView?

Comment: I have two UIImageView objects and only one is changing. In the interface builder i have set the outlets to two UIImageviews correctly. Still it doesn't work.

Comment: Well, something obviously is not correct :).   Maybe "po" the values of self.imageview1 and self.imageview2 and see if they really are different

Answer (score 0):

If your Interface Builder connections are all correct, I'd suggest inspecting your values for `choosePhoto1` and `choosePhoto2`. Are you sure these are set to the correct values when you click the buttons? (Maybe show that code too). I'd guess you are toggling the values of them like so:

```
- (IBAction)btnOneClicked:(id)sender {
  self.choosePhoto1 = YES;
  self.choosePhoto2 = NO;
}
```

Comment: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker   didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
 if(choosePhoto1){self.choosePhoto2=NO;
  NSLog(@"buttonclicked:button1");
  theimageView1.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
}else if(choosePhoto2) {
  self.choosePhoto1=NO;
  NSLog(@"buttonclicked:button2");
  theimageView2.image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
 }
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

Comment: That is really hard to read :/ can you edit your question and add that code or submit it on a site like gist.github.com and link to that?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is, when are `choosePhoto1` and `choosePhoto2` set to `YES`? If they are just initialized to `YES`, that won't work.